# Confusion about generation of database and seeding

Tags: ef-code-first, code-first, entity-framework-4.3, entity-framework-migrations

I am using entity framework code first
and also I have data seeding code

Now when I run my application my database gets generated but is not seeded with my dummy data.
I have to run entity framework once more to get all data populated.

Any idea why and how to fix that so i do not have to run my app 2x to get database and data?

thnx

my context definition file is:

```
 public class Context : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Agency> Agency { get; set; }

      protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
     {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
     }
    }
```

And here is my seeding file

```
public class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<Context>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
    }

    protected override void Seed(Context context)
    {
        GenerateTasks(context);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    private static void GenerateTasks(Context context)
    {
        if (context.Task.Any()) return;
        context.Task.Add(new Task() { Name = "Received" });            
    }
}
```

And hook to create database is:

```
  Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<Context, Configuration>());
  var context = new Context();
  context.Database.Initialize(true);
```

Comment: Show your seeding code and your initialization code.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka what do you mean by initialization code?

Comment: The code that triggers database creation.

Comment: Still I don't understand what do you mean by: *I have to run entity framework once more* Your code is correct and you should have your database seeded immediately after calling `Database.Initialize`

Comment: @LadislavMrnka When i run my application for first time it generate database structure but does not seed my default data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app is an **ASP.NET** one and is a **seperate assembly** from the data layer, then you can, instead of configuring the initialization like you did, configure it directly in the web.config. Maybe this is the reason for your problem.

So if it's an ASP.NET app, you can try the following:

**(1)**

Comment this out:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<Context, Configuration>());
var context = new Context();
context.Database.Initialize(true);
```

**(2)**

In web.config, insert this right at the end before the closing **/configuration** tag:

```
<entityFramework>
<contexts>
  <context type="**fully-qualified name of your context class**,
                 **assembly name of your context**">
    <databaseInitializer type="System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`2[[**fully-qualified name of your context class**, **assembly name of your context**],
                               [**fully-qualified configuration type**, **assembly name of your context**, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral]], EntityFramework"/>
  </context>
</contexts>
```

where **fully-qualified configuration type** is the class with your migrations-configuration (something like [...]Context.Migrations.Configuration)

I use this configuration-approach for myself in my projects and it works well!

Answer (score 0):

That's true. call `context.Tasks.Find(1)` and then it will hit the database.
EF code-first uses this trick to postpone every thing. this way application's startup time *seems* much faster. (but actually it's not!)

Comment: When or where do I need to use call the command: is it before i create seeding data or after?

Comment: Instantiate the dbContext and then call a dummy query. Now db initialization takes place. Otherwise it will be postponed.